# Cannot find symbol for java.net

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, import

I am using NetBeans for Windows 7 with JDK 7. I want to use the Socket class but when I try the import

```
import java.net.*;
```

or

```
import java.net;
```

I get the error :
    "cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class net
    location: package java"

I looked in C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/classlist and "java/net/Socket" is in there. I'm not sure if this indicates anything important.

Also possibly worth noting: in C:/Program Files (x86)/Java, both /jre6 and /jre7 exist.

Comment: looks like some error in your class as a whole. why don´t you add it to your question? (is import java.net; legal?)

Comment: `import java.net` is not legal since there isn't a class called `net` in the `java` package (and it's not possible to create one as the `java` package is special).

Comment: Look for environment variables

Answer (score 3):

`import java.net.*;` is correct.

More specifically [`import java.net.Socket;`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

Make sure that your imports appear after you package declaration, but before your class definition.